# need help parsing a complicated text file

Tags: python, dataframe, data-processing

I have a text file with structure which looks like below, i want to extract the data in a dataframe using python. Dataframe should have PMID along with all the text appearing against Author for each PMID.

Data format

PMID- unique 8digit number
xyz - text (might be multiple lines)
xyz- text (might be multiple lines)
AUTHOR- text (might be multiple lines)
AUTHOR- text(might be multiple lines)

PMID- unique 8digit number
xyz - text (might be multiple lines)
xyz- text (might be multiple lines)
AUTHOR- text (might be multiple lines)
AUTHOR- text(might be multiple lines)

Code i have tried in python is below - i am able to extract all PMIDs but i am not able to figure out logic to attach all Author text against each PMID.

```
for lines in open('pubmed-cancerbiol.txt','r'):
    if(lines[0:4] == 'PMID'):
        print(lines)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, updated the code i have used so far, I am more looking for some guidance on logic. I can figure out the code once i get the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use collect the data in a dictionary with `PMID` as keys and `AUTHOR`s as values.

Say you start with the file

```
from io import StringIO
fo = StringIO(
'''PMID- 12345678
xyz - text (might be multiple lines)
xyz- text (might be multiple lines)
AUTHOR- author1
AUTHOR- author2

PMID- 12345679
xyz - text (might be multiple lines)
xyz- text (might be multiple lines)
AUTHOR- author3
AUTHOR- author4''')
    
# with open(filename, 'r') as fo:
```

Then iterate lines and populate the dictionary

```
records = dict()
pmid = None
for line in fo.readlines():
    if line.startswith('PMID-'):
        pmid = line.split('-')[-1].strip()
        records[pmid] = []
    elif line.startswith('AUTHOR'):
        records[pmid].append(line.split('-')[-1].strip())
```

When creating the dataframe you coud `df = pd.DataFrame(records)` to have each author in a column or join the lists before passing to dataframe constructor

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [', '.join(r) for r in records.values()],
    index=records.keys()
)
```

Output

```
                         0
12345678  author1, author2
12345679  author3, author4
```

Comment: @Bharath thank you, please get used to providing data sample that is meaningful and can be easily pasted into code

Comment: Sure Richie, I would keep that in mind, in fact i am reading on how to reproduce an error and ask a question in more meaningful way. Hope next time onwards I am able to ask questions in a better way. Thanks again for your guidance and help with my query.